# mysql stored procedure group_concat returning null for select in cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-concat

I have a stored procedure where I'm looping through results in a cursor.  The issue I'm having is the license_attributes value is always null when it shouldn't be.  If I execute the select statement outside the stored procedure, or as a debug execute the select statement outside the cursor in the stored procedure, I get the results I'm expecting (not null)

**This is the part of the select that is always returning null in the cursor:**

```
        (SELECT 
            CONCAT('{""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Type__c,'"": {',GROUP_CONCAT(
            '""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Key__c,'"":""',LOWER(sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Value__c),'""'
            ),'}}')
            FROM 
                sf.Asset_Attribute__c 
            WHERE 
                sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c = license_id
            GROUP BY sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c) AS `license_attributes`
```

**Here is the section of the stored proc:**

```
    GETCLOUDACCOUNTS:BEGIN

    DECLARE no_more_cloud_accounts_records boolean DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE company VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE license_status VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE license_id VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE cloud_owner_email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE entitlement_plan VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE role VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE is_trial BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE license_attributes VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE zuora_account_id VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE zuora_account_number VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE zuora_account_status VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE zuora_account_last_invoice_date DATETIME DEFAULT null;
    DECLARE has_active_subscriptions BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;

    DECLARE cloud_accounts_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT
            (SELECT `sf`.`Contact`.`CompanyName__c` FROM `sf`.`Contact` WHERE `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactId`=`sf`.`Contact`.`Id`) AS `company`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key_Status__c` AS `license_status`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key__c` AS `license_id`,
            `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactEmail__c` AS `cloud_owner_email`,
            (SELECT `sf`.`Contact`.`CloudEntitlementPlan__c` FROM `sf`.`Contact` WHERE `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactId`=`sf`.`Contact`.`Id`) AS `entitlement_plan`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`Role__c` AS `role`,
            IF( (SELECT `sf`.`Product2`.`IsCommercial__c` FROM `sf`.`Product2` WHERE `sf`.`Product2`.`Id`=`sf`.`Asset`.`Product2Id`) = 0,true,false ) AS `is_trial`,
            (SELECT 
                CONCAT('{""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Type__c,'"": {',GROUP_CONCAT(
                '""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Key__c,'"":""',LOWER(sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Value__c),'""'
                ),'}}')
                FROM 
                    sf.Asset_Attribute__c 
                WHERE 
                    sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c = license_id
                GROUP BY sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c) AS `license_attributes`
        FROM
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`
        LEFT JOIN `sf`.`Asset`
            ON `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key__c` = `sf`.`Asset`.`Id` 
        JOIN `sf`.`Contact`
            ON `sf`.`Contact`.`Id` = `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`Contact__c`
        WHERE
            `sf`.`Contact`.`ExternalID__c`='someexternalidhere';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_cloud_accounts_records = true;
        SELECT
            (SELECT `sf`.`Contact`.`CompanyName__c` FROM `sf`.`Contact` WHERE `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactId`=`sf`.`Contact`.`Id`) AS `company`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key_Status__c` AS `license_status`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key__c` AS `license_id`,
            `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactEmail__c` AS `cloud_owner_email`,
            (SELECT `sf`.`Contact`.`CloudEntitlementPlan__c` FROM `sf`.`Contact` WHERE `sf`.`Asset`.`ContactId`=`sf`.`Contact`.`Id`) AS `entitlement_plan`,
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`Role__c` AS `role`,
            IF( (SELECT `sf`.`Product2`.`IsCommercial__c` FROM `sf`.`Product2` WHERE `sf`.`Product2`.`Id`=`sf`.`Asset`.`Product2Id`) = 0,true,false ) AS `is_trial`,
            (SELECT 
                CONCAT('{""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Type__c,'"": {',GROUP_CONCAT(
                '""',sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Key__c,'"":""',LOWER(sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Value__c),'""'
                ),'}}')
                FROM 
                    sf.Asset_Attribute__c 
                WHERE 
                    sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c = license_id
                GROUP BY sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c) AS `license_attributes`
        FROM
            `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`
        LEFT JOIN `sf`.`Asset`
            ON `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key__c` = `sf`.`Asset`.`Id` 
        JOIN `sf`.`Contact`
            ON `sf`.`Contact`.`Id` = `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`Contact__c`
        WHERE
            `sf`.`Contact`.`ExternalID__c`=@p_externalId;

    OPEN cloud_accounts_cursor;
    CLOUDACCOUNTSLOOP: loop

        fetch cloud_accounts_cursor into company, license_status, license_id, cloud_owner_email, entitlement_plan, role, is_trial, license_attributes;

        IF is_trial = true THEN
            SET has_active_subscriptions = true;
        END IF;

        SET zuora_account_id = `z`.`getZAccountId`(cloud_owner_email);

        IF zuora_account_id IS NOT NULL THEN
            SELECT `accountNumber`,`status`,`lastInvoiceDate` INTO zuora_account_number,zuora_account_status,zuora_account_last_invoice_date FROM zuora.Account WHERE id=zuora_account_id;

            IF has_active_subscriptions = false THEN
                SET has_active_subscriptions = (SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `z`.`RatePlan`
                    RIGHT JOIN `z`.`ProductRatePlan` ON `z`.`RatePlan`.`productRatePlanId` = `z`.`ProductRatePlan`.`id`
                    LEFT JOIN `z`.`Subscription` ON `z`.`RatePlan`.`subscriptionId` = `z`.`Subscription`.`id`
                    WHERE
                    `z`.`ProductRatePlan`.`wowzaRatePlanCode__c` IN ( (SELECT `code` FROM `z`.`zCloudRatePlanCodes`) )
                    AND `z`.`Subscription`.`status` = 'Active'
                    AND `z`.`Subscription`.`accountId` = zuora_account_id ) > 0, true, false));
            END IF;
        END IF;

        REPLACE INTO `sf`.`zCloudAccounts` (`user_email`,`company`,`license_status`,`license_id`,`cloud_owner_email`,`entitlement_plan`,`role`,`is_trial`,`attributes`,`zuora_account_id`,`zuora_account_number`,`zuora_account_status`,`zuora_account_last_invoice_date`,`has_active_subscriptions`) VALUES(@p_userEmail,company,license_status,license_id,cloud_owner_email,entitlement_plan,role,is_trial,license_attributes,zuora_account_id,zuora_account_number,zuora_account_status,zuora_account_last_invoice_date,has_active_subscriptions);

        IF no_more_cloud_accounts_records THEN
            CLOSE cloud_accounts_cursor;
            LEAVE CLOUDACCOUNTSLOOP;
        end if;

    END LOOP CLOUDACCOUNTSLOOP;

END GETCLOUDACCOUNTS;
```

**If I execute the full select stateout outside of GETCLOUDACCOUNTS block, I get the results I expect:**

```
company, license_status, license_id, cloud_owner_email, entitlement_plan, role, is_trial, license_attributes
Test Company, Active, 02iq0000000jKgMAAU, myemail@email.com, Standard, Owner, 0, {""cloud"": {""cloud_num_247_t_streams"":""0"",""cloud_num_247_p_streams"":""0""}}
Test Company, Active, 02iq0000000xlBBAAY, otheremail@email.com, Standard, Admin;wcl_admin;wcl_support, 0, {""cloud"": {""cloud_num_247_t_streams"":""1"",""cloud_num_247_p_streams"":""1"",""test_attribute"":""true"",""api_access"":""true""}}
```

**But the results inside the block show license_attributes as null:**

```
company, license_status, license_id, cloud_owner_email, entitlement_plan, role, is_trial, license_attributes
Test Company, Active, 02iq0000000jKgMAAU, myemail@email.com, Standard, Owner, 0, null
Test Company, Active, 02iq0000000xlBBAAY, otheremail@email.com, Standard, Admin;wcl_admin;wcl_support, 0, null
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is related to the procedure variable `license_id`.

The correlated subselect in the SELECT list includes

```
 WHERE sf.Asset_Attribute__c.Asset__c = license_id
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Local variables take precedence over column references. Since `license_id` is declared as a variable within the code block,

```
 DECLARE license_id VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT null;
```

the reference to `license_id` in the SELECT statement is a reference to that procedure variable.

Outside the code block, there likely is not a local variable named `license_id`. So that same SQL SELECT statement, that reference to `license_id` is not a reference to a variable, but a reference to a column.

I haven't traced through all of the logic, or the contents of `license_id` variable. But I suspect that explains the difference in the behavior observed with the statement, executed inside the code block vs outside the block.

Comment: Sure enough!  Thank you.  Changed it to reference `sf`.`License_Key_Association__c`.`License_Key__c` instead of license_id variable and voila!

Comment: I'm not sure why the question received a downvote. I don't think it was a bad question. I upvoted the question (+10) not because it's a great question, but to balance out the undeserved downvote.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure why it was down-voted, either.  I thought I fit all the criteria for valid question.

Comment: My preference is to *always* qualify all column references. One big reason for doing that is to insulate the statement from changes... like if later a column with the same name is added to a table used in the query... what was unambiguous before can become ambiguous, breaking the statement. (By qualifying the column references, my statement is insulated from breaking.) Or, as in this case, if a local variable named `license_id` didn't exist, but was later added. Qualifying column references also aids the future reader, by not forcing them to hunt through table definitions for a column name

Comment: Makes perfect sense and I'm convinced to do that moving forward.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can `COALESCE` to take care of NULL values in your GROUP_CONCAT

```
COALESCE(`YourColumnName`,'')
```

You can also use a significantly different string to show you where the NULL value is coming from, so that you can then fix the query.

```
COALESCE(`YourColumnName`,'**UNEXPECTED NULL**')
```